# I'm facing gradle issue while running flutter application using vscode

Tags: flutter

is there any one to help me from this bug. Actually its working fine but I've enabled the flutter-web yesterday, after that I reverted it from then whenever I've create new project every time build failed at gradle script_ remapped....

[image]

Comment: Can you give us more information on the error !

Comment: Firstly refer this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Your question including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post.

Comment: Thanks to @AbdelbakiBoukerche,@code_aks fro the response.
Issue was resolved, actually I deleted the android and gradle folders from C drive from then the issue started. To resolve that I did was I've reinstalled Android Studio.